# Python animation updates

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have written a simple python code for animation. The code creates random points and then plots them during the animation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = 10*np.random.rand(10,1)
y = 10*np.random.rand(10,1)


fig = plt.figure()
ax  = plt.axes(aspect='equal',xlim =(-10,10), ylim = (-10,10))
plts = ax.plot([], [], 'o-')

def init():
  plts.set_data([],[])
  return plts

def animate(num,x,y,plots,skip):
    plts[0].set_data(x[:num*skip],y[:num*skip])
    return plts

skip = 1
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, 
                              animate, 
                              frames=10, 
                              fargs =(x,y,plts,skip),
                              interval=1000)


plt.show()
```

During the animation, the code plots all the points.
Can someone tell me how to plot only one point in a frame and clear the previous point ?
[image: Random point plot animation output]

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you plot all the points in the list, up to index `num*skip`. Each frame `num` is increased by 1 and therefore one additional point is plotted.

In order to plot only the `num`th point, simply use

```
plts[0].set_data(x[num],y[num])
```